# Flask WTForms form not submitting but outputs no validation errors

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am try to create a basic accounting package using Flask and I am a bit stuck with validating a particular form.  It is working for another form within the same app, but for some reason I can't figure out why this one won't work as well.  The form appears as it should in the web-browser, and I can enter data as normal, but when I come to submit the form, it just seems to reload the page.  My database does not get updated, and after some digging I discovered that my `if form.validate_on_submit()` isn't catching anything.

There is no error thrown in the stack trace either.

I shall post the relevant sections of my files below.

My `views.py`:

```
@app.route('/dashboard/<nickname>/work-orders/add/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def work_orders_add(nickname):
ca = check_active(nickname)
if ca[1] == True:
    form = AddWorkOrderForm()
    u = User.query.get(current_user.id)
    c = u.contacts.order_by('name').all()
    form.requestor.choices = [(contact, contact.name) for contact in c]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        db.session.add(WorkOrder(requestor = form.requestor.data,
            date = form.date.data,
            notes = form.notes.data,
            total = 0.00,
            completed = form.completed.data,
            user = g.user))
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('work_orders', nickname=current_user.nickname))
    elif request.method != "POST":
        form.date.data = datetime.date.today()
    else: return "didn't work" 
    return render_template('work_orders_add.html',
        user = ca[0],
        title = "New Work Order",
        form = form)
else: return redirect(url_for('work_orders', nickname=current_user.nickname))
```

My `forms.py`:

```
class AddWorkOrderForm(Form)
    requestor = SelectField('requestor', coerce=unicode)
    date = DateField('date')
    notes = TextAreaField('notes')
    completed = BooleanField('completed', default = False)
```

My `models.py`:

```
class WorkOrder(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'workorder'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    date = db.Column(db.String(64))
    notes = db.Column(db.String(1024))
    total = db.Column(db.Float)
    completed = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    contact_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contact.id'))
    items = db.relationship('WorkOrderItem', primaryjoin="WorkOrder.id==WorkOrderItem.work_order_id", backref = 'order')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<WorkOrder %r>' % (self.id)
```

My HTML file:

```
{% extends "_is_logged.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="work_order">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>Requestor: {{ form.requestor() }}</p>
    <p>Date: {{ form.date() }}</p>
    <p>Notes: {{ form.notes(size=70) }}</p>
    <p>Completed: {{ form.completed() }}</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add Work Order"></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you add a `{% for field_name, field_errors in form.errors.items() %}<p>{{ field_name }} <ul>{% for error in field_errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>{% endfor %}</p>` to your template file?

Comment: I have tried adding that in, but nothing seems to change. Does your code need to be changed at all to but put into my template file? Or should a simple copy and paste have worked?

Comment: Nope, it should have just worked, as long as you put it inside the `content` block ...

Comment: Double checked; it was inside the `content` block but doesn't produce anything sadly.

Comment: Still not fixed this if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you put `print` statements in each of your blocks - does it go where you expect it to?  (And what happens if before your `return render_template` you put a `print "Form Errors:", form.errors`?

Comment: are you using HTML5? If so, the form won't be submitted due to the `<form action=""` [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-action) requires a non-empty action attribute.

Comment: Try printing `form.errors` and `request.method` in `work_orders_add` method!

Comment: Very, very, very old post, but thanks @SeanVieira for your suggestion.  I got "The CSRF token is missing.", and so found the fix.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Iarissa spotted it long ago. The form has no action value so as a first step I suggest you change this:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="work_order">
```

into:

```
<form action="{{url_for('work_orders_add')}}" method="POST" name="work_order">
```

Also from the code given, it looks like the function `work_orders_add(nickname)` does not seem properly indented. The if statement should be included in the function so that you would have:

```
@app.route('/dashboard/<nickname>/work-orders/add/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def work_orders_add(nickname):
    ca = check_active(nickname)
    if ca[1] == True:
        form = AddWorkOrderForm()
        u = User.query.get(current_user.id)
        c = u.contacts.order_by('name').all()
        form.requestor.choices = [(contact, contact.name) for contact in c]
        if form.validate_on_submit():
```